# Audio player not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, firefox, jwplayer

[The site](http://www.ptm.org/daily-radio) I am working on is using some code from its previous website from a few years ago. The audio player doesn't load in firefox (click the listen button, audio player will open in popup). I think it's using [jw player](https://www.jwplayer.com/).

It's fine in Chrome but in Firefox it just doesn't appear. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

That site use jwplayer 5 (very old), so the player needs Flash player correctly activated on Firefox (https://helpx.adobe.com/it/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-firefox.html)

On Chrome, maybe you have the flash player blocked (by default with new Chrome versions) and the player fallback to mp3 file, or the flash plugin is correctly activated on Firefox